# Webpack code splitting, System.import route not found if imported from separate file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

The `PlainRoute` **Router** logic works perfectly when implemented as follows ...

```
const componentRoutes = {
  component   : Home,
  path        : '/',
  indexRoute  : Index,
  childRoutes : [
    {
      path: 'child',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('./Child/components/child')
          .then(module => cb(null, module.default))
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However when I try to declare in a separated file

**Child/index.js**

```
export default () => ({
  path: 'child',
  getComponent(location, cb) {
    System.import('./components/child')
      .then(module => cb(null, module.default))
  }
})
```

And do:

```
import Child from './Child'

const componentRoutes = {
  component   : Home,
  path        : '/',
  indexRoute  : Index,
  childRoutes : [
    Child
  ]
}
```

it no longer finds the **child** `route`.

HashHistory is used as a history for the Router. And project structure is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Child/index.js` you export a function, but then you pass in that function to the `childRoutes`. What you really want is the object that is returned from that function. Just call the function `Child()`:

```
childRoutes : [
  Child()
]
```

Or you can export the object directly without wrapping it in a function in `Child/index.js`:

```
export default {
  path: 'child',
  getComponent(location, cb) {
    System.import('./components/child')
     .then(module => cb(null, module.default))
  }
}
```